# Unable to pass SIGTERM to a process in a bash script

Tags: bash, signals

I'm running Terraform from a script in a pipeline. I would like to ensure that if the pipeline job is aborted, Terraform receives SIGTERM.

```
_term() {
  tf_pid="$(pidof terraform)"
  kill -TERM ${tf_pid}
  wait ${tf_pid}
}

trap _term SIGTERM
...
...
...
terraform "$@"
```

With this approach, SIGTERM is not propagated. However, it is propagated if I call `terraform` this way in my script:

```
terraform "$@" & wait $!
```

Why is that?

Comment: I need to mention, that I'm not happy with the solution, because I plan to pipe the process output. And if the output is piped, then `$!` doesn't capture the `terraform` PID, instead, it captures the PID of the last process in the pipe.

Comment: Closing as I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46525435/how-to-immediately-trap-a-signal-to-an-interactive-bash-shell